# When do real, analytic, monotonic functions on an interval extend to univalent functions on an open region of the complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Suppose I have a real, analytic function $f(x)$ which is monotonic on some connected, open subset of the real line $W \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and such that $f'(x)>0$ on $W$. Let me naturally include this function into the complex plane $f(x) \rightarrow f(z)$. When can I guarantee that there is some open region of the complex plane $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ where the function $f(z)$ is univalent and such that $W \subseteq D$?

Comment: Take $f(x)=x^3$ around $0$. But maybe it is true if we instead require $f'(x)\ne0$ everywhere?

Comment: Actually, $x^3$ is a good example of a function which satisfies my criteria. Take $D$ to be the open region of the complex plane bounded by $z = r e^{\pm \pi i/3}$ with $r \in [0, \infty)$. The function $z^3$ is univalent in this region and therefore, when restricted to the part of the real line contained in $D$, it is analytic and monotonic. How can I sharpen my question? I have changed the question a little to ask when a similar situation can happen.

Comment: you clearly need connectedness so $W$ needs to be an open interval (finite or infinite) as otherwise, you cannot even guarantee $f$ injective on $W$; I think that may be sufficient but still have to think about it

Comment: ok - I have added connected too